# Formik: How to void maximum depth exceeded when using enableReinitialize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, tailwind-css, formik

I have form using formik in but it always keep showing maximum depth exceeded when i enable enableReinitialize in formik.

I have attached my project in here

https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-haze-3nfp9p?file=/src/App.js

I try figure out how to avoid in this since it used on a Modal
Below this current code:

```
type ModalAddPropType = {
  t: (key: any) => any;
  labelModal: string;
  handleLabelModal: (val: string) => void;
};

const ModalAdd: FC<ModalAddPropType> = ({
  t,
  labelModal,
  handleLabelModal,
}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [isErrorStoreEventAgenda, setIsErrorStoreEventAgenda] =
    useState<boolean>(false);
  const [formDirty, setFormDirty] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const InitialAddEventAgendaFormValue: CreateAgendaRequestType = {
    eventId: "",
    agendaName: "",
    sessionName: "",
    agendaSpeaker: "",
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(),
    descriptions: "",
  };
  function initiliazeValue() {
    const InitialAddEventAgendaFormValue: CreateAgendaRequestType = {
      eventId: "",
      agendaName: "",
      sessionName: "",
      agendaSpeaker: "",
      start: new Date(),
      end: new Date(),
      descriptions: "",
    };
    return InitialAddEventAgendaFormValue;
  }

  const { mutate: mutateStoreEventAgenda, error: errorStoreEventAgenda } =
    useStoreEventAgenda(
      (res: EventAgendaType) => {
        dispatch(updateIsLoadingAction({ isLoading: false }));

        toast.success(t("text.add_agenda-event_success"));

        navigate("/admin/event");
      },
      (err: any) => {
        setIsErrorStoreEventAgenda(true);
        toast.error(err.message);
      }
    );

  const addEventAgendaForm = useFormik({
    initialValues: InitialAddEventAgendaFormValue,
    validationSchema: createEventAgendaFormValidationSchema,
    onSubmit: async (values: CreateAgendaRequestType) => {
      dispatch(updateIsLoadingAction({ isLoading: true }));
      setFormDirty(false);
      mutateStoreEventAgenda(values);
    },
  });

  const $targetEl: HTMLElement | null =
    document.getElementById("message-alert");
  const $triggerEl: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById(
    "dismissing-message-alert"
  );

  const options: DismissOptions = {
    transition: "transition-opacity",
    duration: 300,
    timing: "ease-out",
    onHide: () => {
      setIsErrorStoreEventAgenda(false);
    },
  };

  new Dismiss($targetEl, $triggerEl, options);

  if (isErrorStoreEventAgenda) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(updateIsLoadingAction({ isLoading: false }));
    }, 500);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setFormDirty(addEventAgendaForm.dirty);
  }, [addEventAgendaForm.dirty]);

  useBeforeUnload(
    useCallback(
      (e) => {
        if (formDirty) {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.returnValue = "";
        }
      },
      [formDirty]
    )
  );

  function closeModal() {
    console.log("hi");
    handleLabelModal("undefined");
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    initiliazeValue;
  }, [initiliazeValue]);

  return (
    <>
      <Modal dismissible show={labelModal === "add"} onClose={closeModal}>
        <Modal.Header>{t("Add Agenda")}</Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <div className="space-y-6">
            <form>
              <div className="flex flex-col">
                {/* Agenda Title */}
                <EVSInput
                  t={t}
                  label="label.agenda-name"
                  type="text"
                  name="eventAgenda.name"
                  placeholder="label.agenda-name"
                  handleOnChange={addEventAgendaForm.handleChange}
                  handleOnBlur={addEventAgendaForm.handleBlur}
                  value={addEventAgendaForm.values.agendaName}
                  touched={addEventAgendaForm.touched.agendaName}
                  errors={addEventAgendaForm.errors.agendaName}
                />
                {/* Agenda Session */}
                <EVSInput
                  t={t}
                  label="label.session-name"
                  type="text"
                  name="eventAgenda.sessionName"
                  placeholder="label.session-name"
                  handleOnChange={addEventAgendaForm.handleChange}
                  handleOnBlur={addEventAgendaForm.handleBlur}
                  value={addEventAgendaForm.values.sessionName}
                  touched={addEventAgendaForm.touched.sessionName}
                  errors={addEventAgendaForm.errors.sessionName}
                />
                {/* Agenda Speaker */}
                <EVSInput
                  t={t}
                  label="label.agenda-speaker"
                  type="text"
                  name="eventAgenda.speaker"
                  placeholder="label.agenda-speaker"
                  handleOnChange={addEventAgendaForm.handleChange}
                  handleOnBlur={addEventAgendaForm.handleBlur}
                  value={addEventAgendaForm.values.agendaSpeaker}
                  touched={addEventAgendaForm.touched.agendaSpeaker}
                  errors={addEventAgendaForm.errors.agendaSpeaker}
                />
                <div className="flex flex-row gap-3">
                  {/* Agenda Start */}
                  <div>
                    <label
                      htmlFor="text"
                      className="block py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white"
                    >
                      {"label.start-time"}
                    </label>
                    <Flatpickr
                      name="eventAgenda.start"
                      className="py-2 bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                      options={{
                        enableTime: true,
                        noCalendar: true,
                        dateFormat: "H:i",
                      }}
                    />
                  </div>
                  {/* Agenda End */}
                  <div>
                    <label
                      htmlFor="text"
                      className="block py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white"
                    >
                      {"label.end-time"}
                    </label>
                    <Flatpickr
                      name="eventAgenda.end"
                      className="py-2 bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                      options={{
                        enableTime: true,
                        noCalendar: true,
                        dateFormat: "H:i",
                      }}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                {/* Event Agenda Descriptions */}
                <EVSTextArea
                  t={t}
                  label="label.agenda-descriptions"
                  name="eventAgenda.descriptions"
                  placeholder="label.agenda-descriptions"
                  className="md:col-span-2"
                  rows={3}
                  handleOnChange={addEventAgendaForm.handleChange}
                  handleOnBlur={addEventAgendaForm.handleBlur}
                  value={addEventAgendaForm.values.descriptions}
                  touched={addEventAgendaForm.touched.descriptions}
                  errors={addEventAgendaForm.errors.descriptions}
                />
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button color="gray" onClick={closeModal}>
            Decline
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default ModalAdd;
```

Comment: Please check if this PR works : https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/pull/3793